# Apache PySpark - Failed to connect to master 7077

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I set up Spark and HDFS after watching this [video](https://youtu.be/hRtInGQhBxs). The only difference is that I did it on a server (ubuntu) and not on a VM.

On the server, everything works perfect. Now I wanted to access it from my local machine (Windows) with PySpark.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("spark://ubuntu-spark:7077").appName("test").getOrCreate()
spark.stop()
```

However, here I get the following error messages:

```
22/11/12 10:38:35 WARN Shell: Did not find winutils.exe: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset. -see 
https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WindowsProblems
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use 
setLogLevel(newLevel).
22/11/12 10:38:35 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your 
platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
22/11/12 10:38:37 WARN StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master 
ubuntu-spark:7077     
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: ...
```

According to other posts, the DNS should be correct. I got this from the Spark Master website (at port 8080):

```
URL: spark://ubuntu-spark:7077
Alive Workers: 1
Cores in use: 2 Total, 0 Used
Memory in use: 6.8 GiB Total, 0.0 B Used
Resources in use:
Applications: 0 Running, 0 Completed
Drivers: 0 Running, 0 Completed
Status: ALIVE
```

The ports are open. I also don't understand the following message: "HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset." Hadoop is configured on the server. Why should I do the same thing locally again? My expectation would be that I can use Spark like an API or am I wrong?

Thank you very much for your help. If you need any configuration files I can provide them.

Comment: you'll have to add a few environment paths before using spark. check some guide that would help with the set up paths.

Comment: Do you know a good guide here? I have tried several now, but I still get the same error. What can I look for there?

Comment: You should provide spark-env.bat for windows

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop should not be necessary for the code shown since you're not using HDFS, but the log is saying it's looking on your *Windows machine* for those settings.

DNS needs to work between your windows machine and wherever your server is running (a VM can still be server, so it's unclear where you're running this). Start debugging with `ping spark-master` to check, or you should be able to open `spark-master:8080`  from Windows browser instance as well.

If you only want to run Spark code, and don't care if it's distributed, you could just use Docker on Windows - https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks

Or setup Pycharm all locally for the same